# get current status of gphoto2

Tags: macos, sh, libgphoto2

I have gphoto running with a --wait-event-and-download argument, so that the pictures I take using my infrared remote are saved to the computer.

I have a second script set up to interrupt the wait process and take a picture programatically, like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
# shootnow.sh - stop the current gphoto2 process (if it exists),
# shoot a new image, then start a new wait-event process.

pkill -INT gphoto2     #send interrupt (i.e. ctrl+c) to gphoto2
sleep 0.1              #avoid the process ownership error
gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download  #take a picture now
gphoto2 --wait-event-and-download   #start a new wait-event process
```

But I want to make sure the first wait-event process is not currently downloading an image before I go interrupting it (which causes a messy situation where images fill up the camera's ram, preventing further operation). So the second script should be something more like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# shootnow-with-check.sh - stop the current gphoto2 process (if it exists 
# and isn't currently downloading an image), shoot a new image, then start 
# a new wait-event process.

shootnow() {  # same as previously, but now in a function
    pkill -INT gphoto2
    sleep 0.1
    gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download
    gphoto2 --wait-event-and-download
}

if [ ***current output line of gphoto2 process doesnt start with "Downloading"*** ] then
    shootnow
else
    echo "Capture aborted - a picture was just taken and is being saved."
fi
```

Can anyone help me with that if statement? Can I read the current output line of a running gphoto process?

Comment: I am looking at using `expect` first to run the `gphoto --wait-event`, then monitor for the existence of the "Downloading" string, and when it occurs, turn some system-wide variable (e.g. "gphotoIsBusy") to 1, turning it off again when the "Saving" string is detected. Anyone know how to make expect continually monitor, turning a variable on/off like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed this with a script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
# gphoto2-expect.sh
# use expect to monitor gphoto2 during --capture-image-and-download with
# --interval=-1, adding in SIGUSR1 functionality except during a
# download event.

echo "Prepping system for camera"
killall PTPCamera
expect << 'EOS'
puts "Starting capture..."
if [catch "spawn gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --interval=-1" gp_pid] {
  Log $ERROR "Unable to start gphoto2.\n$gp_pid\n"
  return 0
}

trap {exec kill -SIGUSR1 $gp_pid} SIGUSR1
set timeout -1
expect {
  -i $spawn_id
  "Downloading" {
    trap {send_user "\n Ignoring request as currently downloading"} SIGUSR1 ; exp_continue
  }
  "Saving file as" {
    sleep 0.1
    trap {exec kill -SIGUSR1 $gp_pid} SIGUSR1 ; exp_continue
  }
}

EOS
```

which could be triggered with another script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# trigger.sh - trigger an immediate capture
var=$(pidof expect)
kill -SIGUSR1 "$var"
```

Comment: Note. pidof is a custom program - (obviously) gets the pid of a named process.

Answer (score 1):

gphoto2 has an option --hook-script FILENAME.
FILENAME has to be an executeable script, and is called on some gphoto2 events. The script then has an environment variable ACTION that you can use for your purpose.
For example: You call gphoto2 with

```
gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --hook-script myhook.sh
```

and myhook.sh looks like

```
#! /bin/bash
echo $ACTION
```

then myhook.sh will be called 4 times. Its output is

```
init
start
download
stop
```

see man gphoto2 for details.

Comment: I looked into --hook-script but ultimately found it wouldn't work for my purpose, because the script is only called once an image has FINISHED downloading. But I needed to detect when gphoto2 was CURRENTLY downloading an image in order to decide whether to allow an interrupt or not.

Comment: ... but thank you for pointing out that the script has to be executable, that I didn't know. Didn't help me, but useful to know nonetheless.

Comment: I'm using option --hookscript very often (and with success)  to wait for the beginning of a download, it works fine. What content of $ACTION does myhook.sh show to you?